# How to know if a Kohana request is an internal one?

Tags: request, kohana, kohana-3, internal

I'm writing an API using Kohana. Each external request must be signed by the client to be accepted.

However, I also sometime need to do internal requests by building a `Request` object and calling `execute()`. In these cases, the signature is unnecessary since I know the request is safe. So I need to know that the request was internal so that I can skip the signature check.

So is there any way to find out if the request was manually created using a `Request` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the is_initial() method of the request object? Using this method, you can determine if a request is a sub request.

[Kohana 3.2 API, Request - is_initial()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Request#is_initial)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could easily solve this issue by setting some sort of static variable your app can check. If it's not FALSE, then you know it's internal.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up doing it: I've overridden the `Request` object and added a `is_server_side` property to it. Now, when I create the request, I just set this to true so that I know it's been created server-side:

```
$request = Request::factory($url);
$request->is_server_side(true);
$response = $request->execute();
```

Then later in the controller receiving the request:

```
if ($this->request->is_server_side()) {
    // Skip signature check
} else {
    // Do signature check
}
```

And here is the overridden request class in **application/classes/request.php**:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Request extends Kohana_Request {

    protected $is_server_side_ = false;

    public function is_server_side($v = null) {
        if ($v === null) return $this->is_server_side_;
        $this->is_server_side_ = $v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking through Request it looks like your new request would be considered an internal request but does not have any special flags it sets to tell you this.  Look at 782 to 832 in Kohana_Request...nothing to help you.

With that, I'd suggest extending the Kohana_Request_Internal to add a flag that shows it as internal and pulling that in your app when you need to check if it is internal/all others.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to the source code. It looks like for internal requests, the `client` property is set to `new Request_Client_Internal` and to `new Request_Client_External` for external requests. Will do some tests with that to see if it's reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for `is_external` method:
http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Request#is_external

Comment: I saw this property but this is different. This is to check if a request comes from outside the domain - i.e. if http://example.com calls http://mydomain.com/someaction, `is_external` will be true. However if I type http://mydomain.com/someaction directly on the browser bar, `is_external` will be false. So I cannot use it because the request still comes from outside (not directly from within the server).

Answer (score 0):

Kohana 3.3 in the controller :

```
$this->request->is_initial()
```

http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Request#is_initial